# Recreating a dynamic php array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a php array which is created from data in an sql database.
All I want to do is recreate that identical array on another site.

I can print_r it no worries. But how would I output the structure of the array so that I can go as follows on the new site.

```
$newvar = array(.....);
```

I'm sure it's a very simply question, But I can't find an answer.

Comment: I think you want [`var_export`](http://php.net/var_export).

Comment: For insert the array in other db, you should iterate it and build the sql, there is no other option.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in my question. It's been fixed. var_export is actually what I was asking for, however serialize seems like the better method now. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[serialize](http://www.php.net/manual/es/function.serialize.php) Try this function. I think this is what you need

Answer (score 1):

you can use json_encode to send your array and keep the structure of your array.

Comment: This answer doesn't request clarification. It is an answer and therefore should be in the answer section. Thanks for your answer. I'll upvote as it does exactly as I need however I think serialize it is the more appropriate method for this task. Thanks